# Trying to find a Horror book involving a book that when read the reader believes they are a character in that book

Tags: identification-request

The story is about a book that comes out of nowhere (the author is dead and connected to cults). Whenever a person reads the book they believe they are a character within that book and they attempt to convert people

- I remember it having a three word title that is the same as the above mentioned book.
- It was part of a trilogy.
- The cover of the first book had a Jester.
- I cannot remember an author or publication date, but it was after 2010 as far as I know.

Comment: Just to be clear, the real book has a three-word title with a jester on the cover? And then there's a book within that story that has the same title, and which causes characters in the book to believe that they're characters in the book within the book? How far down the rabbit hole does it go?

Comment: Yep, unfortunately I can't remember a ton about it; the story is about a book that comes out of nowhere(the author is dead and connected to cults). Whenever a person reads the book they believe they are a character within that book and they attempt to convert people. Unfortunately I cannot remember much more.

Answer (score 2):

This is Robin Jarvis' [Dancing Jax](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8713020-dancing-jax), first in the Dancing Jax trilogy. From Goodreads,

> Now, a group of teenagers have decided to hang out in the old haunted house. Dismissing the fears of the others, their leader Jezza goes down into the basement… and comes back up with a children’s book, full of strange and colourful tales of a playing-card world, a fairytale world, full of Jacks, Queens and Kings, unicorns and wolves.
>
> But the book is no fairytale. Written by Austerly Fellows, a mysterious turn-of-the-century occultist, it just might be the gateway to something terrifying…and awfully final. As the children and teenagers of the town are swept up by its terrible power, swept into its seductive world, something has begun that could usher in hell on earth. Soon, the only people standing in its way are a young boy with a sci-fi obsession, and his dad – an unassuming maths teacher called Martin…